# Can't get duplicate items to group as I would like them to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

So I've got a query for a report that is giving me almost exactly what I need.

The code gives me all of the items in a "kit," tells me how many of those items there are supposed to be in the kit, and gives me the difference between the items in the kit and the number that's supposed to be there.

When there are different lot numbers for the same product code in a kit, it splits the product code onto two line items even though I'm doing a group by product code. This makes it appear as though there are items missing from the kit for that product code, but in reality they are not missing because when you put the separate lots together you get the full quantity.

```
SELECT plItem.ProductCode,
       plItem.[Description],
       sum(ISNULL(ProductContent.Qty, 0))                              AS KitQty,
       ISNULL(KitBomItems.Qty, 0)                                      AS BOMQty,
       sum(ISNULL(ProductContent.Qty, 0)) - ISNULL(KitBomItems.Qty, 0) AS Diff
FROM   KitBomItems
       JOIN ProductList AS plItem
         ON KitBomItems.ProductListID = plItem.ID
            AND KitBomItems.KitBomListID = @AssemblyID
       LEFT JOIN ProductContent
         ON ProductContent.ProductCode = plItem.ProductCode
            AND ProductContent.StatusID = @KitID
GROUP  BY plItem.ProductCode,
          plItem.[Description],
          ProductContent.Qty,
          KitBomItems.Qty
```

See the attachment for the result! Thanks for any help :)[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're grouping by too many columns - you shouldn't be grouping by `ProductContent.Qty`. Try this

```
SELECT      
    plItem.ProductCode,             
    plItem.[Description],           
    sum(ISNULL(ProductContent.Qty,0)) AS KitQty,            
    ISNULL(KitBomItems.Qty,0) as BOMQty,            
    sum(ISNULL(ProductContent.Qty,0)) - ISNULL(KitBomItems.Qty,0) AS Diff       
    FROM KitBomItems 
        JOIN ProductList AS plItem ON KitBomItems.ProductListID = plItem.ID 
        AND KitBomItems.KitBomListID = @AssemblyID          
        LEFT JOIN ProductContent ON ProductContent.ProductCode = plItem.ProductCode 
        AND ProductContent.StatusID = @KitID 
    group by 
        plItem.ProductCode,          
        plItem.[Description],
        KitBomItems.Qty
```